# C# - Literal control vulnerable to XSS attack

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals

I'm using a literal to display some javascript on a product page control.  Basically what I'm doing is in my code behind I'm declaring a new stringbuilder, writing the script while inserting some dynamic variables to populate the script then setting the literal text to the stringbuilder.  This leaves me open to xss attacks.  What can I do to prevent this?

EDIT. Here is an example of the stringbuilder.  when the page gets loaded the xss vulnerability occurs right after the javascript is generated.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            //loop through items in the collection
            for (int i = 0; i < _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                //add +1 to each item
                sb.AppendFormat("mboxCreate(\"product_productpage_rec{0}\",", i+1);
                sb.Append("\"entity.id=" + _prodID + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.categoryId=" + _categoryID + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.name=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].Title + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.pageURL=" + Request.Url.ToString() + "\",");
                //The following value has been taken from the productImageControl code behind.
                //Might have to refactor in future as a property of the image control.
                string filename = AppSettingsManager.Current.ProductImagePathLarge + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].Sku
                    + AppSettingsManager.Current.ProductImageExtension;
                sb.Append("\"entity.thumbnailURL=" + filename + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.inventory=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection.Count + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.value=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].ActualPrice + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.ProductItemID=" + _prod.ActiveProductItemCollection[i].Sku + "\",");
                sb.Append("\"entity.addToCartImg=~/Images/Buttons/btn_AddToCartFlat.gif\");<");
                //The last line has to be /script. < inserted on prev line. do not change it or bad things will happen.            
                sb.Append("/script>");
            }
            this.LiteralMBoxScript.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Could someone edit this to make the code readable?

Comment: Your last comment is wrong.  There is nothing wrong with appending `</script>` whole in C#.  (That issue only applies in an inline `<script>` tag in HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly encode any user-generated data that you're putting into the Javascript.

In ASP.Net 4.0, you can call [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx).
In earlier versions, you can use the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I am using asp.net4.  i edited the question to include more detail

Comment: @tking: You need to call `JavaScriptStringEncode` on each of the values as you assemble the string.

Comment: and how would i do that?  I'm not familiar with the method.  Something like this?

Comment: sb.Append("\"entity.id=" + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(_prodID) + "\",");

Comment: ok i try that it fails on build with cannot convert from int to string.  i tried changing to sbAppendFormat as well to no avail.

Comment: If I cast it to string the build works.  Lets see what it looks like on page now...

Comment: @tking: You don't need to escape `int` values.  (An `int` cannot cannot contain quotes, arrows, or other XSS payloads)  You should only call `JavaScriptStringEncode` on strings.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent XSS you could [HTML encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx) the value.

Comment: Usually javascript should be placed in separate .js files and not generated by string builders or any server side code.

Comment: Darin, please look at the edited question to see why I cannot use an external javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could write your javascript to read the user supplied data off of the page.  This will result in less javascript code, and a faster page load.

If you are using JQuery for example, you can use the $.Parent() and $.Children() selectors to traverse the DOM to the appropriate form controls to reference information about that particular record in the loop.

Here is a relatively simple sample

```
function doSomething(context) {
var IDInput = $(context).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td.id').children('.hidden');
//Do something with the value
IDInput.val();
}
```

This would work with the following html example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="Do Something"/></td>
<td class="id">Hidden ID Value <input type="hidden" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="Do Something"/></td>
<td class="id">Hidden ID Value <input class="hidden" type="hidden" value="2"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you no longer have to write javascript functions that take the ID as a parameter, meaning you don't need to dynamically generate the functions on the button, and can load them in the header in a separate JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is just your own script being written to the literal, you are no more open to attacks than if you simply included a js file on your site. If on the otherhand your script is interspersed with user supplied data of any kind, then you need to sanitize that data before you write it to the page.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you could output the value using the `<%: theText %>` syntax.

Comment: No, he can't.  Read the question.